# Null php json while econde a query from mySQL with accents

Tags: php, mysql, json

When I try to encode on a JSON a query from MySQL database that gives me a null JSON when the words have accents eg. " olá " , " à " etc

my php code:

```
$sql = "SELECT `name`
          FROM `login`
         WHERE `id`='1';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
     
$emparray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

my database:

```
id  |  name | 
1   |  Olá  |
```

Comment: What version php are you using? The `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` constant was added in php 5.4 meaning if you are on an older version `json_encode` would return null and throw a notice (undefined constant) and warning (invalid argument) errors. Outside of that, I don't see an issue with the code (https://3v4l.org/HqIvU) so I would start with the usual, check the error logs.

Comment: Which encoding and collation are you using for table "login"? Did you try to fill $emparray manually from PHP?

Comment: my php version is 5.6.23

Comment: step one: [ensure you are utf-8 all the way down](http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/740553). Don't expect encoding compatibiliy to work without explicitly telling everything *exactly* what you need.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn: terminology: json doesn't "throw" anything. it issues a notice. none of PHP's procedural functions will ever throw anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*json_encode* assumes that the result is encoded in UTF-8, if it is not returned null

> first verify that your database server is configured with UTF_8
>
> *or add the set_charset before the consultation*

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
```

> Use [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to modify the HTTP header, UTF-8 all the way through

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Answer (score -1):

> Its working fine check [Click Here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/khs9-1wpd)

```
<?php
 echo json_encode("Olá ",JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```